# Promox: rsync copy of datastore results in backup size much larger than original

Tags: filesystems, proxmox

I'm running Proxmox VE 5.4.1

I have created a datastore on a 2TB disk, /dev/sdb. This is where I store all my virtual machines

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1                    1.8T  947G  794G  55% /datastore
```

As you can see only 947G is used so far.

Now I have a logical volume 1.4TB mounted on /backup and I'm using rsync to copy the entire contents of my datastore to /backup.

The problem is that the backup drive is getting filled up, even though I have more than enough storage to backup everything.

I ran a quick comparison of one of the image directories. Its roughly 50% larger than the original. Why is this? Why can't I backup using rsync?

```
du -sh 104 /datastore/images/104
113G    104
82G /datastore/images/104
```

Comment: Which rsync options are you using? VM images are often stored as sparse files and a simple rsync will ignore that. I read something about using `--sparse` and `--inplace` together for sparse files, but I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: Thanks, I think this it. https://gergap.wordpress.com/2013/08/10/rsync-and-sparse-files/